# Replacing nil in hash with 0 and place in a csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

Hi I have a hash something like this:

```
{"f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08"=>nil, "d1063ee8-1e22-4e8c-b5f5-76a4f8d3cdbe"=>"500"}
```

which was created using the below code:

```
result = {}
source1.each {|k, v| result[k] = source2[k] if source2[k] != v }
```

When I try to store this hash in a csv, I get the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)
```

I'm hoping replacing nil with 0 should work. This is the current code I have:

```
def relacenill(h)
  h.each_with_object({}) { |(k,v),g|
    g[k] = (Hash === v) ?  relacenill(v) : v ? v : '0' }
end
```

But this doesn't seem to be working. Can you please help?

Comment: How specifically are you trying to store your hash in a CSV?

Comment: `result` has my hash. I then use 
`CSV.open(csvfilename, "w") {|csv| result.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem.to_s} }` to place the data in csv

Comment: But that should work fine if you drop that strange `to_s` call on `elem`. I don't see where you're getting a TypeError from what you're doing anyway, a NoMethodError but not a TypeError.

Comment: Works for me without `to_a` and `to_s` call, try this `CSV.open(fname, 'w') { |csv| hash.each { |each| csv << each }}`

Comment: I generate the result using `result = {}
source1.each {|k, v| result[k] = source2[k] if source2[k] != v }
`
I am then trying to place this in a csv file

Comment: Turned out one of my filename arguments was `nil`. This caused issues in data insertion into the csv. Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

below code will take the hash (let's say x is your hash) and will look up if any of its values is nil, will set it to 0

```
2.3.1 :001 > x = {:a => 5, :b => nil} 
2.3.1 :002 > x.each {|k,v| x[k] = x[k].nil? ? 0 : x[k] }
=> {:a=>5, :b=>0} 


2.3.1 :009 > require 'csv'
 => true 
2.3.1 :010 > x
 => {:a=>5, :b=>0} 
2.3.1 :011 > CSV.open('lorem.csv', 'wb') {|csv| x.to_a.each {|e| csv << e}}
 => [[:a, 5], [:b, 0]] 
2.3.1 :012 > exit
$ cat lorem.csv 
a,5
b,0
```

Comment: This is working well... However, when I place the replaced hash into the csv I still get the error `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`.

Comment: i've checked with writing to  a csv file, and seemed ok. could you please check again?

Comment: `x.each { |k,v| x[k] = v || 0 }` instead of ternary?

Answer (score 1):

```
hash = {"f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08"=>nil, "d1063ee8-1e22-4e8c-b5f5-76a4f8d3cdbe"=>"500"}

hash = hash.reduce({}) do |acc, object| 
    acc[object.first] = object.last.nil? ? '0' : object.last
    acc
  end
# => {"f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08"=>"0", "d1063ee8-1e22-4e8c-b5f5-76a4f8d3cdbe"=>"500"}
```

Comment: his is working well... However, when I place the replaced hash into the csv I still get the error `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)`

Comment: How do you place the hash into the csv? How do you convert the hash into a string? Which information do you need to be in the csv.

Comment: Maybe use `object.last.nil?` instead of `object.last == nil`.

Comment: @LukasBaliak: Thx, that's better. At the moment I do a lot of php, so I   ignore unintendet the beauty of ruby.

Answer (score 0):

Your code:

```
CSV.open(filename, "w") {|csv| result.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem.to_s} }

# => undefined method `map' for "[\"f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08\", nil]":String
```

Change it to:

```
CSV.open(filename, "w") {|csv| result.to_a.each {|elem| csv << elem} }

# => [["f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08", nil], ["d1063ee8-1e22-4e8c-b5f5-76a4f8d3cdbe", "500"]]
```

Hope that solved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = {
  "f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08" => nil, 
  "d1063ee8-1e22-4e8c-b5f5-76a4f8d3cdbe" => "500"
}

data_without_nils = data.each_with_object({}){ |(k, v), h| h[k] = v || '0' }
#=> {
#=>   "f8053d79-9ae8-4d78-888a-b866db12ce08" => "0", 
#=>   "d1063ee8-1e22-4e8c-b5f5-76a4f8d3cdbe"=>"500"
#=> }
```